# Data representation of complex numbers in Scheme

Tags: scheme, complex-numbers

```
(define (complex-num x y)
      (cons x y))
(define (real x) 
      (car x)) 
(define (imag x) 
       (cdr x))
```

Is it right? Or maybe you can suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: This question needs more context. Can you tell us what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Scheme from R6RS has a full numeric tower so I suggest complex numbers in Scheme to be the data structure for complex numbers in Scheme. The procedures   `make-polar`, `make-rectangular`, `real-part`, and `imag-part` is included in the language as well as reactangular literls like `2+3i`. Thus using `cons` is ridiculous unless it is just to learn how to implement features in the language. Btw: Why use `x` and `y`? Is it obvious which is the real part there? Also since `real` and `imag` takes `x` does that mean that it's the same type of parameter as the first in `complex-num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a correct way to represent complex numbers in Scheme. It's also possible to alias the procedures, because you're calling them directly:

```
(define complex-num cons)
(define real car)
(define imag cdr)
```

... But it's a matter of taste, and anyway your solution is easier to understand.

Comment: When you just alias you loose the documentation part of the code so it is harder to understand the intended contract.